# Relation between kernels of homomorphisms and the semidirect product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I'm reading Abstract Algebra of Dummit and I got stuck on this point. When we try to build the semi-direct product of 2 group predefined, such as $H$ and $K$, then all the semi-direct product groups is determined by the homomorphism from $K$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$. The problem is to determine which couple of result groups are isomorphic to each other.

For example, we have 2 homomorphisms $\varphi_{1}, \varphi_{2}$. In some problems they reason that if $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi_{1}) \cong \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi_{2})$, then 2 semidirect product groups of $H$ and $K$ defined by $\varphi_{1}$ and $\varphi_{2}$ are isomorphic, too. Can any one please explain for me whether this is true in general? If not, in which case this is true, and how to prove that?

One more thing, if two kernels are not isomorphic, how can we prove that two semidirect product groups are not isomorphic?

Thanks so much.

Comment: In what problems do they reason that? Can you give some link or quote?

Comment: Certainly you'll need much stronger hypotheses than $\ker(\phi_1) \cong \ker(\phi_2)$. It is very common for $\ker(\phi_1) = \ker(\phi_2) = 1$ amongst non-isomorphic semi-direct products.

Comment: Yes, for example , consider semidirect product of 2 groups: $T = Z_{2}$ and $V = Z_{2} \times Z_{2}$, they consider that there're 3 homomorphism from $V$ to $Aut(T)$ by specifying their kernels as one of three subgroups of order 2 in $V$, and since 3 kernels are isomorphic, then 3 semidirect product groups are isomorphic

Comment: I've already updated the question. If 2 kernels are not isomorphic, how can we prove that 2 semidirect product groups are not isomorphic, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you misread “kernel” versus “image”?

Comment: No, I can assure that I read right. That's why I think about it and get stuck for a long time. If you have that book, you can read page 183, example group order 12, case 2. And also the exercise 7 page 185. Can you think about it and explain for me? Thanks so much

Comment: I just saw this response. This is a quirk of $C_2 \times C_2$. Not only are the kernels isomorphic, but there is only one map with each kernel and the kernels are conjugate in the automorphism group of $C_2 \times C_2$.