# Relation between semidirect products of groups and kernels of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I want to ask a question related to semidirect products.

> If we have two groups $G$ and $H$ and two homomorphisms $\varphi_{1}, \varphi_{2}: H \to \operatorname{Aut(G)}$ and we know that $\ker(\varphi_{1})$ not isomorphic to $\ker(\varphi_{2})$, then can we make sure that semidirect products defined by the two homomorphisms are not isomorphic. If yes, then how?

Thanks so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Read page 49 of this excellent little book http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html for some criteria when two semidirect products are isomorphic.

Comment: Sorry, but how can those 3 lemmas deduce what I asked? I know all 3 lemmas before, but proving 2 group is not isomorphic is another thing. Thanks for showing me a great book.

Comment: Proving non-isomorphism in this generality is not feasible. There are certainly infinite counterexamples. I have had trouble finding finite counterexamples, but I would be surprised if they did not exist.

Comment: Since this is probably a followup to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420992/relation-between-kernel-of-homomorphism-and-the-semidirect-product-group I answered in enough generality to apply to that exercise, and gave a counterexample of very small size to your literal question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a $p$-group and $H$ is a $q$-group for different primes $p,q$.

Then $G$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G \rtimes H$ and $H$ is specified up to conjugacy as a Sylow $q$-subgroup.

In particular, for any two semi-direct products $X_i = G \rtimes_{\phi_i} H$ and any isomorphism $f:X_1 \to X_2$ we are guaranteed that $f(G)=G$ and $f(H)$ is $X_2$-conjugate to $H$. In other words, there is an inner automorphism $\nu$ of $X_2$ such that the composition $X_1 \xrightarrow{f} X_2 \xrightarrow{\nu} X_2 = X_1 \xrightarrow{\bar f} X_2$ has the property that $\bar f(G) = G$ and $\bar f(H) = H$.

Consider the centralizer $C_i = C_H(G)$ inside the two groups $X_i$. $$\begin{array}{rl}
C_i 
&= \{ (1,h) : (1,h)\cdot_i (g,1) = (g,1) \cdot_i (1,h) \forall g \in G \} \\
&= \{ (1,h) : (\phi_i(h)(g),h) = (g,h) \forall g \in G \} \\
&= \{ (1,h) : \phi_i(h)(g) = g \forall g \in G \} \\
&= \{ (1,h) : \phi_i(h) = 1 \} \\
&= \{ (1,h) : h \in \ker(\phi_i) \} \\
\end{array}
$$

In other words, $C_i$ is the kernel of $\phi_i$. Now $\ker(\phi_1) \neq \ker(\phi_2)$ is not particular relevant. What we care about is whether $\bar f(C_1) = C_2$ (which it must, if $f$ really is an isomorphism). However, $\bar f$ restricted to $H$ is easily seen to be an automorphism of $H$, so what matters is whether there is an automorphism of $H$ that takes $\ker(\phi_1)$ to $\ker(\phi_2)$. If there is not, then there can be no $\bar f$.

On page 187 of Dummit–Foote, exercise 7c, all of these properties are satisfied.

*Technical conditions*: We needed $G$ characteristic in $X_i$ and $H^1(H,G)=0$. If $G$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $X$ (for instance a Sylow), then Schur–Zassenhaus guarantees the relevant properties are satisfied. If $G$ is abelian, then we don't need the cohomology condition, just the characteristic.

### Counterexample

Without the technical conditions we can have counterexamples. For example let $G=H$ be nonabelian of order 6. Let $\phi_1(h)(g) = g$ and $\phi_2(h)(g) = hgh^{-1}$. Then $\ker(\phi_1) = H$ and $\ker(\phi_2) = 1$ but $X_1 \cong X_2$. In this case $G$ is not characteristic, but we can achieve the isomorphism with an $f$ such that $f(G)=G$. In this case however, there is no $\bar f$ with $\bar f(G) = G$ and $\bar f(H) = H$.

In particular, we have non-isomorphic kernels with isomorphic semi-direct products.

Comment: In relation to your counter-example, there is the following result of Arzhantseva, Lafont and Minasyan (from their paper "Isomorphism versus commensurability for a class of finitely presented groups"): Suppose that $G$ is a group which has no epimorphisms onto $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\phi, \psi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Then the following are equivalent.
(i) $G\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $G\rtimes_{\psi}\mathbb{Z}$ ; (ii) $\widehat{\phi} \in \operatorname{Out}(G)$ is conjugate to one of the two elements $\widehat{\psi}, \widehat{\psi}^{−1} \in \operatorname{Out}(G)$.

Comment: Thanks so much Jack, it makes the group classification problem easier. I really appreciate it...